# I want to crop image using Bezier curve in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i draw bezier curve in android , can any one suggest some references or existing source code that helps me to understand bezier curve .i want to crop image in my android app using any close path like Bezier Path. i know it is possible using rectangle but i want crop in different shape. like i make one shape using touch and want to crop that image so how it is possible. any suggestion or help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You best bet would be to use the [quadTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#quadTo%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) and [cubicTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#cubicTo%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) and other utility methods available in the [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) class. All you have to do is determine the control points.

I have written a simple tutorial on how to use Path and PathMeasure to draw lines, curves, etc., You may find it here:

http://c05mic.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/animating-a-bitmap-using-path-and-pathmeasure-android/